# How do I send a list of words, one by one on a facebook chat using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

stringOfWords = "this is a sentance I want to send word by word"
listOfWords = stringOfWords.split(" ")

driver = webdriver.Edge('C:/Users/Andrej/OneDrive - UKIM, FINKI/Kodovi/Python/msedgedriver.exe')
user = '*myusername*'
pw = '*mypassword*' 

driver.get("https://facebook.com")
sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"email\"]").send_keys(user)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"pass\"]").send_keys(pw)
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/label/input').click()
sleep(6)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a').click()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='*the name of the person I want to send it to*']").click()

#everything works fine until here
msgbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/span/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')

for word in listOfWords:
    if word != ' ':
        msgbox.send_keys(word)
        sleep(2)
        msgbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        sleep(2)
```

It works fine until the second word. It sends the first one but after the second one it crashes and gives me a "StaleElementReferenceException".

I know I'm doing something very obviously wrong but I can't find a solution anywhere

(I'm using Edge Chromium as a browser but I get the same results on Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try below solution ::


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('disable-infobars');
options.add_argument("disable-notifications");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
stringOfWords = "this is a sentance I want to send word by word"
listOfWords = stringOfWords.split(" ")


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://facebook.com')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"email\"]").send_keys("credential")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"pass\"]").send_keys("credential")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Log In']"))).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@name='mercurymessages']//div[@class='_2n_9']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Friend name')]"))).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@role, 'presentation')]//div[contains(@aria-describedby, 'placeholder')]")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
text = "this is a sentance I want to send word by word"
for world in text.split():
    element.send_keys(world)
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I got the same error again at the same spot.

"selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: I'm still getting the same error :/ idk what's going on

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m5TqUZYp

It sends the first word than crashes, as usual

Comment: check now , I have changed locator , i think its a profile specific

Comment: This solved it for me! I just had to add a sleep after the enter press because it was going so fast that it crashed sometimes, but that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me, check comments below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://facebook.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

el = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
el.send_keys("username")
el = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pass")))
el.send_keys("password")
el.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.refresh() # intentionally here, otherwise, in my case, was throwing an err error: "the element is no longer attached to the DOM"...

el = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Chat']")))
el.click()

el = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Kelly')]"))) # change to the full or partial friend name
el.click()

el = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'notranslate')]")))
el.click()

s = "this is a sentEnce I want to send word by word"
for w in s.split():
    el.send_keys(w)
    el.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

---

[image]

Comment: crashes after login with the error: "File "C:\Users\Andrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "

Comment: It didn't crash when I tested it. The traceback you sent isn't helpful. On which element did it crash? It may be due to different browser or language.

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't copy the full error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Andrej/OneDrive - UKIM, FINKI/Kodovi/Python/bottybot.py", line 21, in <module>
    el = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Chat']")))
  File "C:\Users\Andrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

It logs in and then does nothing. So for some reason it can't open the messages.

Comment: Does it say `chat` on the lower right when you first open facebook? https://i.imgur.com/C2KoP3U.jpg, If not, you've to change that part of the code to match the title of the `Chat` window.

Comment: You can also try matching that specific element more generically, i.e.: `el = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Chat')]")))`